# Filtering on a datetime column in ASPxGridView using ShowHeaderFilterButton="true"

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am trying to filter on a datetime column using ShowHeaderFilterButton="true".

When I click the control, it shows dates such as 26/01/2015 00:00:00.

Then it returns "No data to display".

Values in the column are 26/01/2015 14:47:14 and 26/01/2015 14:47:23.

I was expecting them to show! I guess it is showing no data because it is not an exact match.

How can I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working. Added

```
    OnProcessColumnAutoFilter ="ASPxGridView1_ProcessColumnAutoFilter"
```

and

```
    <Settings  ShowFilterRow="True" />
```

to the Gridview.
And this code:

```
    protected void ASPxGridView1_ProcessColumnAutoFilter(object sender,
DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewAutoFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column != ASPxGridView1.Columns["completionDate"]) return;

       if (e.Kind == DevExpress.Web.GridViewAutoFilterEventKind.CreateCriteria)
        {
            // Creates a new filter criterion and applies it.
            e.Criteria = null;
            DateTime yourDate;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(e.Value, out yourDate)) return;
            yourDate = yourDate.Date;
            DateTime nextDay = yourDate.AddDays(1);
            e.Criteria = (new OperandProperty("completionDate") >= yourDate) & (new OperandProperty("completionDate") < nextDay);
         }
    }
```